# In how many days $Y$ alone finish the work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$X$ and $Y$ do a piece of work in $30$ days .They work together for $6$ days and then $X$ quits and $Y$ finishes the work in $32$ more days.In how many days would $Y$ be able to finish the work alone?

note:$X+Y=1/30$
then $X+Y=6/30=1/5$ finished work 
remaining $1-1/5=4/5$ work only by $Y$ in 32 more days 
so $\frac54\cdot32=40$ days
is this correct?.

Comment: note:x+y=1/30
then x+y=6/30=1/5 finished work 
remaining 1-1/5=4/5 work only by y in 32 more days 
so 5/4*32=40 days
is this correct?.

Comment: Yes!! You are correct

Answer (score 1):

> Work done by both in one day $\displaystyle =\frac1{30}$
>   Work done by both in 6 days $\displaystyle=\frac6{30}=\frac15$
>   Remaining work $\displaystyle=\frac45$
>   Y does $\displaystyle\frac45$<sup>th</sup> work in $\displaystyle=32$ days.
>   Y will do whole work in $\displaystyle=\frac{32}{\frac45}\times1=40$ days.

Yes you are correct!